# Calling mysql function PASSWORD from mysql cli error in mysql ver 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am using mysql version 8.0

From mysql cli I am trying to call the function PASSWORD. So I have used the following command :

**mysql > select PASSWORD('123');**

But I get the following error in this case :
**ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('123')' at line 1**

I have also tries the following :

**mysql > select PASSWORD("123");**

**mysql > select PASSWORD(`123`);**

But each one give the same error. I have also googled a lot but could not find any solution for this.

How can I solve this

Regards,
Tanvir

Comment: What version of mysql do you use? Password function was removed as of 8.0.11

Comment: I am using mysql 8.0.11. Actually i want to do something like this :                                        mysql> update user set Password = password('test') where host='localhost' and User='root';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mysql documentation on the [password() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) says:

> This function was removed in MySQL 8.0.11.

As mysql documentation says, you should use [alter user statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html) to change the password:

> ALTER USER syntax is the preferred statement for account alterations, including assigning passwords. For example:
>
> ```
> ALTER USER user IDENTIFIED BY 'auth_string'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`PASSWORD()` was deprecated in 5.7 and removed in version 8. Far more secure ways of handling passwords are available, and you should consider using one.

Comment: Actually i want to do something like this : mysql> update user set Password = password('test') where host='localhost' and User='root';

Answer (score 0):

Updating the ACL system tables directly (or any system tables for that matter) is not a very sustainable practice.

Why would you need to execute
UPDATE mysql.user SET password = hash('clear-text-password') WHERE host = 'foo' and user = 'bar'
followed by a FLUSH PRIVILEGES (!)
when you can just do:
ALTER USER foo@bar IDENTIFIED BY 'clear-text-password' ?